# How semi-synthetic cell with artificial DNA works

Tags: dna, cell

I know that by now this is old new but I heard that a cell that used a synthetic pair of nucleotides, called X and Y, have been made. My question was, how did the cell understand the X and Y nucleotides during translation and how was it even represented in mRNA? It must have been represented differently, possibly using X and Y nucleotides only. That's the only way I can think of that causes the cell to make 172 amino acids instead of the usual 20. By the way I read this in the Discover magazine, January issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The altered E Coli still only made use of the regular 20 amino acids (presumably).

Looking at the [original citation](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v509/n7500/full/nature13314.html), Malyshev et al didn't characterize the RNA in their altered E Coli at all. All they did was add free X and Y to the E Coli's growth medium and add a gene to the E Coli that expressed an `algal nucleotide triphosphate transporter`. Malyshev et al then demonstrated that replication (copying of the DNA) proceeds normally and in such a way as to preserve the X and Y content.

So no information as to whether any of the products downstream from the DNA (ie mRNA, proteins, etc) were affected by their modifications.